# Two part post request to get CSRF Token then make another request

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm attempting to access data by first logging in to the following site:
https://accessns.nscorp.com/accessNS/login/

It looks like it sends this requests to the backend:

- Request URL: https://accessns.nscorp.com/accessNS/rest/auth/login
- Request Method: POST
- Status Code: 200 OK
- Remote Address:167.121.11.85:443
- Referrer    Policy:    no-referrer-when-downgrade

When I send that request in python, I'm able to get a response back with a CSRF Token.

Next, I would like to access:

- Request URL:
  https://accessns.nscorp.com/accessNS/rest/backend/ServicesIndustrial/services/industrial2/v2/onsite/details
- Request Method: POST
- Status Code: 200 OK Remote Address:
       167.121.11.85:443
- Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Which takes the following headers:

- Accept: */*
- Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
- Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
- Connection: keep-alive
- Content-Length: 58
- Content-Type: application/json
- Cookie: [some cookies]
- CSRFTOKEN: [from auth request above]
- Host: accessns.nscorp.com
- Origin: https://accessns.nscorp.com
- Referer: https://accessns.nscorp.com/accessNS/legacy/
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36

Payload:
{userId: "username", classCode: "classcode", stationCode: "stationcode"}

My code fails when I attempt to use CSRF Token and cookies from the authorization request into the secondary request, but it doesn't fail when I manually login to the site, get the token/cookies, and hard code them into python.  In fact, all I need in terms of headers for the secodary request is CSRF Token and cookies to get a viable response.

```
with requests.Session() as s:

    login = {'Id': 'username', 'pwd': 'password'}
    auth = s.post('https://accessns.nscorp.com/accessNS/rest/auth/login', 
                   json=login)


    headers = {}
    headers['CSRFTOKEN'] = auth.json()['response']['token']
    headers['Cookie'] = '; '.join('='.join((i.name, i.value)) for i in 
                                  auth.cookies)


    payload = {'userId': 'username', 'classCode': 'classcode', 
               'stationCode': 'stationcode'}

    url = 
    'https://accessns.nscorp.com/accessNS/rest/backend/ServicesIndustrial/ 
     services/industrial2/v2/onsite/details'

    inv= s.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

    print(inv.json())
```

I expect to get a json response with the data I've requests, however, using my code, I get:

{'time': 1559217902355, 'message': 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.. Reference number: 1559217902355', 'cause': 'Invalid user input', 'isError': True}, which to me seems like it's an issue with my headers/payload, or I'm missing an intermediate step.

When I hardcode the csrf token/cookies and don't use a requests session, I get the response I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, my code works fine.  Turns out the secondary request was being made to the wrong URL, which is strange because that's what's listed in every developer console I've checked.